# Getting undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass Ruby on Rails Guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Okay, I've been searching for a question here thats exactly the same as mine and I can't find one, so I'm forced to ask it myself. I'm following the guide on here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I ran into this error saying: "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass" for my Edit Article page.

Here is my extracted source:

```
 <h1>Editing article</h1>
 <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
   <% if @article.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
            this article from being saved: </h2>
```

And here is my trace:

app/views/articles/edit.html.erb:4:in block in _app_views_articles_edit_html_erb___778692675__618464548

app/views/articles/edit.html.erb:3:in _app_views_articles_edit_html_erb___778692675__618464548

Here is my action Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def edit
    @articles = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end


 end
```

And here is my edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing article</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path(@article), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article 
        from being saved: </h2>
     <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>


  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
<%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Variable Definition**

Something you might want to consider, alongside `Arup`'s answer, is the error itself:

> "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass"

What you're getting back is an exception because you're trying to call a method on a `nil` class object. As *Arup* pointed out, this is generally caused by your calling of an `@instance_variable` without defining it first

I want to highlight the fact that your error says the problem is you have an *undefined method* for your object. Most would treat the problem as your method is undefined for some reason; in reality the problem is you don't have the object defined.

--

**Fix**

The way to fix the error, as pointed out by *Arup* is to reference the `@instance variable` that's defined in the `edit` method, like this:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
       @article = Article.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/articles/edit.html.erb
<%= @article.errors %>
```

Something else you will want to consider is the following:

```
#app/views/articles/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have a typo with the instance variable.

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
```

should be

```
<% if @articles.errors.any? %>
```

Because inside the *controller* action `#edit`, you have defined `@articles` not `@article`. But it should be named `@article` since it's a single article. Thus keep `<% if @article.errors.any? %>` as it is, change the `#edit` method as

```
def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Remember *instance variables* returns `nil`, if you attempt to use it before defining it in Ruby. The same happened in your case. You defined `@articles`, but used `@article`, which was not defined by you before attempting to use it, thus returns `nil`. And `nil.errors` throws the error as you see.

Comment: But it *should* be named `@article` since it's a single article.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that @article is nil (null)

In your controller, edit the new action, so it looks like this:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

Refresh the web page, and there is no more error.

Answer (score 1):

Edit new action in controller

def new

@article = Article.new

end

Since your instance of article is nill.